# Is there any way to define variables in classes without any default value?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I want the following behaviour:

```
class RealEstate:
    rooms
```

Suddenly the following results in an Unresolved reference Error: NameError: name 'rooms' is not defined.

I am aware that I can assign None to the variable:

```
class RealEstate:
    rooms = None
```

Or define the type:

```
class RealEstate:
    rooms: float
```

Both will work. But it is not what I want. I want it as simple as possible and with less typing. Is there any way to make the first example work? Maybe some Metaclasses magic, some brilliant decorators, extending some special classes or libraries that can help?

Comment: And what should the value of `RealEstate.rooms` be?

Comment: @DeepSpace it should be None, because I am not assigning anything to it.

Comment: But you asked for "without any default value?" `None` is a default value, so you need to explicitly set it

Comment: Or even in general, any default value will work for me. I just want to define the variable name in the class scope. I dont care about its value.

Comment: @DeepSpace it is the default value, but not asigning a valur in a class scope throws and error

Comment: @mkrieger1 a library I am writing for. Extension for the library scrapy. I want to simplify the process of defining variables as much as possible.

Comment: I mean, why do you need to write this at all. Why don't you just write `class RealEstate:` and then nothing?

Comment: @mkrieger1 obviously, as the question suggests I want to define the Variable. I want its name in the class scope.

Comment: @mkrieger1 "In Python, all variables have a value" -> this is not true. The third example shows it. "rooms: float" does not define a value.

Comment: It sounds like you *could* use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) but apparently you don't want that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I would use them, no problem. But they did not allow it either. In a dataclass you need to define the variable with either a type or a value too. So nothing is changing

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't "define" a variable by writing its name alone. It will be evaluated as an expression and if it doesn't exist already it will raise a `NameError`.

You can either

- "define" a variable by using an assignment `name = value` (it binds a name to a value at runtime, and you need to specify the value), or
- "define" a variable by using a type annotation `name: type` (it associates a name with a type, for which you need to specify the type, but does not automatically create the name or any value at runtime).